# Linear Regression on Time Series

Tags: time-series, linear-regression

I have a csv file containing values of X and Y variables. i have been asked to use this to build a linear regression model that can predict the current value of the variable  based on its previous historical values (say 4 historical values). and my model should have following form.

W = + WX+ + QWXQ + SWXS + YWXY +

(+, Q, S, Y, ) are supposedly the parameters that should be found.

Now this looks very confusing and i don't know where to begin with it. I have relatively little experience with time series forecasting but i understand all machine learning principles. Can someone guide me in the right direction.

Comment: I'm working with time series right now. Overall you would approach it similarly to other machine learning problems, though there are some caveats. My understanding is that linear regression is not the optimal model for a time series. You should look into ARIMA models or SARIMA or even SARIMAX if you have a situation that is seasonal and/or has exogenous variables.